Solving $y''+9y= \sin(3t)$ with the Laplace Transform
So I'm trying to solve the initial value problem $y''+9y=\sin(3t)$ where $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=-1$ specifically with the Laplace Transform but am running into trouble.
This problem is much easier to solve by guessing a solution of the form $y_p(t)=\alpha te^{3it}$ and taking the imaginary part at the end, for what it's worth.
Taking the Laplace Transform of both sides and solving for $\mathcal L(y)$ we get:
$$\mathcal L(y)=\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}+\frac{s}{s^2+9}-\frac{1}{s^2+9} \tag{1}$$
Now a professor said this problem is "straightforward" using Laplace Transforms and that the answer is $$y(t)=\frac{1}{6}t\sin(3t)+\cos(3t)-\frac{1}{3}\sin(3t)\tag{2}$$
and I see how they got the $\cos(3t)$ and $-\frac{1}{3}\sin(3t)$ from the last two terms in $(1)$ above, but just not the $\frac{1}{6}t\sin(3t)$ term. Wolfram Alpha does not agree with my professor.
Clearly for $t\sin(at)$ or $t\cos(at)$ we at least need some $s$ variable in the numerator.
Any help would be appreciated.

$\mathcal{L}{t \sin(at)} = \frac{2as}{(s^2+a^2)^2}$

@Yimin I know that. But there is no $s$ variable in the numerator of the first term.

then the answer from your professor is wrong, and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}{\frac{9}{(s^2+9)^2}} = \sin(3t)\ast \sin(3t) = \int_0^t \sin(3\tau)\sin(3(t-\tau)) d\tau = \frac{1}{6}(\sin(3t) - 3t\cos(3t))$

Following the examples in the comments and here, we use two methods to find the inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}$.
The Convolution Theorem:
Note that $$\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{s^2+9}\cdot\frac{3}{s^2+9}$$
so that $$\mathcal L^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}\right)=\frac{1}{3}(f\ast g)(t)$$ where $f(t)=g(t)=\sin3t.$ So
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{3}(\sin3t\ast \sin3t)& =\frac{1}{3}\int_0^t\sin(3u)\cdot\sin(3(t-u)) \space du\\
 & = \frac{1}{6}\int_0^t(\cos(6u-3t)-\cos(3t))\space du\\
& = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{6}\sin(6u-3t)-u\cos(3t)\big|_0^t\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{6}\sin(3t)-t\cos(3t)-\frac{1}{6}\sin(-3t)\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{18}\sin(3t)-\frac{1}{6}t\cos(3t).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then $y(t)=\frac{1}{18}\sin(3t)-\frac{1}{6}t\cos(3t)+\cos(3t)-\frac{1}{3}\sin(3t)=\cos(3t)-\frac{5}{18}\sin(3t)-\frac{1}{6}t\cos(3t).$
Partial Fractions:
We may use the unconventional partial fraction decomposition (motivated by what we want our inverse Laplace Transform to be): $$\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}=\frac{As}{(s^2+9)^2}+\frac{B(s^2-9)}{(s^2+9)^2}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+9}.$$
Clearing denominators, we get
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
3&=As+B(s^2-9)+(Cs+D)(s^2+9)\\
& =As+Bs^2-9B+Cs^3+9Cs+Ds^2+9D\\
& = Cs^3+(B+D)s^2+(A+9C)s+(-9B+9D). 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus $A=C=0$, $B = -D$, and $D-B=1/3$ so that $D=1/6$ and $B=-1/6.$ So therefore we have $$\frac{3}{(s^2+9)^2}=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{s^2+9}-\frac{1}{6}\frac{s^2-9}{(s^2+9)^2}=\frac{1}{18}\frac{3}{s^2+9}-\frac{1}{6}\frac{s^2-9}{(s^2+9)^2}$$
which gives the same inverse Laplace Transform as the convolution method.
